# why is my HorizontalPagerIndicator " java.lang.NullPointerException " in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin

I am making a dictionary application and there are quiz sections in the dictionary application. There are various questions in the quiz sections and the number of questions can vary, for example, the number of questions in one category may be 20, while the number of questions in another category may be 30. I also made a horizontal page for the questions to make it look nice for the user. I also added a horizontal page indicator to tell users to scroll sideways, but it throws `"java.lang.NullPointerException "`.

What can be the problem ? I don't understand too much from horizontal page indicator and horizontal page, but I want to use it in this way, can anyone help? I share my codes

**My code**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DisplayQuestionsScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: DisplayScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val state = viewModel.state.value
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = state.questions!!.size)
println("state size ${state.questions.size}")

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                backgroundColor = bar,
                title = {

                    Text(
                        text = "questions",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 22.sp
                    )

                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.TestYourSelfMainScreen.route)
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Go Back"
                        )
                    }
                }

            )

        }
    ) {

        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->

                val question = state.questions[page]

                DisplayQuestionItem(question = question)


            }

            HorizontalPagerIndicator(
                pagerState = pagerState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    .padding(16.dp),
            )
        }


        LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState) {

            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(state.questions.size)
        }



    }


}
```

`println("state size ${state.questions.size}")` The state value comes as `0` in println, most likely the problem stems from here. The reason for this may be `0` because the view model is not full yet, so it may be `nullpointer exception` or the app is crashing because of this. How can I overcome this problem.

But when I remove the horizontal page indicator, the state size comes properly, but for some reason it comes as `0` when I add horizontal page indicator.

**my view pager version in build gradle**

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.14.0"
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.14.0"
```

**my viewmodel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class DisplayScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val getQuestionsByIdentifierUseCase: GetQuestionsByIdentifierUseCase
) : ViewModel() {


    private val testYourSelfTitle: String? = savedStateHandle.get(TEST_YOURSELF_LETTER_ARGUMENT_KEY)
    private var delimiter = " "
    private val parts = testYourSelfTitle!!.split(delimiter)



    private val _state = mutableStateOf(DisplayQuestionsState())
    var state: State<DisplayQuestionsState> = _state



    init {

        println(parts)
        loadQuestions(parts[0])
    }


    private fun loadQuestions(letter: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            getQuestionsByIdentifierUseCase.getQuestionsByIdentifier(letter).collect { item ->

                _state.value = state.value.copy(
                    questions = item
                )

            }


        }

    }




}
```

**error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.accompanist.pager.PagerState.getCurrentPageOffset(PagerState.kt:734)
        at com.google.accompanist.pager.PagerIndicatorKt$HorizontalPagerIndicator$1$2$1.invoke-Bjo55l4-Bjo55l4(PagerIndicator.kt:90)
        at com.google.accompanist.pager.PagerIndicatorKt$HorizontalPagerIndicator$1$2$1.invoke(PagerIndicator.kt:89)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.OffsetPxModifier$measure$1.invoke(Offset.kt:202)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.OffsetPxModifier$measure$1.invoke(Offset.kt:201)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.placeAt-f8xVGno(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:101)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:184)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$5.invoke(Box.kt:165)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$5.invoke(Box.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:960)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:930)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place(Placeable.kt:367)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place$default(Placeable.kt:191)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1$measure$4.invoke(RowColumnImpl.kt:259)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1$measure$4.invoke(RowColumnImpl.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:960)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:930)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:359)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:179)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:663)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:662)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.placeAt-f8xVGno(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:101)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place(Placeable.kt:367)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place$default(Placeable.kt:191)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:322)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:602)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:960)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:930)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:184)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:123)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:960)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:930)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:393)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:266)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:407)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:406)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.placeAt-f8xVGno(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:101)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:184)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:123)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:960)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:945)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:930)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2098)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.replace(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:173)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.replace$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:818)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:280)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:208)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:740)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner$DefaultImpls.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:196)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:937)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22018)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:682)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:688)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:786)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4579)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4290)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3517)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2286)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8948)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for accompanist version 0.27.0

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.27.0"
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.27.0"
```

Code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class, ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun DisplayQuestionsScreen() {
    val questionList = remember {
        listOf(
            "Question 1",
            "Question 2",
            "Question 3",
            "Question 4",
            "Question 5",
            "Question 6",
        )
    }
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            count = questionList.size
        ) { page ->
            val question = questionList[page]
            Text(
                text = question,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .requiredHeight(256.dp),
            )
        }

        HorizontalPagerIndicator(
            pagerState = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also explain why OP was getting NullPointerException, and how this code avoids that?

Comment: @pushpull your code doesnt work unfortunately. My version in build gradle is 0.14.0. For some reason it doesn't work when I change this version.

Comment: I edited my code can you look again please.